# SSH Agent admitted failure to sign using the keys

Tags: debian, ssh-agent, gdm3

I have upgraded my debian from wheezy to jessie.

A ssh-agent is started when I launch my wm (awesome launch via gdm3), I can do ssh-add
The env vars about ssh are correctly set.

```
ps aux |grep ssh-agent
aurel     2185  0.0  0.0  10688   340 ?        Ss   23:41   0:00 ssh-agent

env |grep -i ssh
SSH_AGENT_PID=2185
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-GP1JjseHlBR0/agent.2184
```

I check and the key is known

```
ssh-add -l
2048 ac:70:e5:fc:19:dc:82:5d:60:11:c4:98:63:02:47:11 /home/aurel/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

But when I try to ssh I get an error:

```
ssh data
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
```

A workaround is to launch a new agent

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

but I need to do it for each term.

What's wrong with the first launched agent ?

Comment: Seems to be a X problem, if I add the key without the `-c` opt I don't have the issue

Comment: Test with kdm, and gnome, the issue is still here.

Comment: I have tried with a new user, at the first logging this works, at the second this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution,

As root user run

```
dpkg-reconfigure libpam-runtime
```

uncheck `Authenticate using SSH keys and start ssh-agent`